# gtkmm's answer to gdk_threads_enter() or SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: swing, gtk, gtkmm

I am writing a gtkmm3 application and I need to create and show new GUI elements from a non-GUI thread. Specifically, I am trying to add a tab to a notebook.

I create the notebook in the gui thread like so:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

if(!Glib::thread_supported()) Glib::thread_init();

Gtk::Window window;

notebook = new Gtk::Notebook();
window.add(*notebook);
notebook -> show();

Worker bee;
bee.start();

return app->run(window);
```

and the I create and add a new tab like so:

```
Gtk::Label label("label");
Gtk::Label child("child");
notebook -> append_page(child, label);
notebook -> show_all();
```

If I insert the tab creation code before `notebook->show()` it works fine. But if I put the tab creation code into its own worker thread, the new tab never shows.

I'm guessing that the failure has to do with the fact that the new tab is created on the worker thread and that violates gtkmm's GUI stuff on the GUI thread convention.

The trouble is that the worker thread is responsible for creating new tabs, and I don't know how many tabs to create at compile time.

In APIs like Swing, and gtk+ there are mechanisms to handle this case. In Swing there is an invokeLater method that allows me to pass a lambda to the GUI thread for invokation, and gtk+ uses gdk_threads_enter/leave to ensure that only one thread is playing the GUI at once.

What is gtkmm's answer to this issue?

Comment: `gdk_threads_enter()` is no longer the GTK+ solution. `gdk_threads_idle_add()` is the new solution; it works exactly like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. I don't know what the gtkmm equivalent is though, but it shouldn't be too hard to find... (and even then other than the lack of C++ features I'm not sure why you couldn't just call the GDK functions anyway...)

Comment: as @andlabs said you can use Idle_add [example here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-idle-functions.html.en) or use Dispatcher ([docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-using-glib-dispatcher.html.en))

Answer (score 0):

In general you should just avoid ever using GTK+ (or gtkmm) UI API from anything but the main thread. It's not meant to work.

You need to let the main thread respond when the other thread says that it should, instead of actually doing the UI work in the other thread. People like to use Glib::Dispatcher for this with gtkmm: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-using-glib-dispatcher.html.en .

But also think hard about whether you really need another thread at all. It might be fine to do the work in an idle handler: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-idle-functions.html.en

Comment: I don't really want another thread, and I only thought that I needed one because I'd never seen this idle function mechanism. If I had a simple void function taking no parameters, what would be the syntax to attach it to signal_idle()?

Comment: If I had a simple  function `void loop()`, what would be the syntax to attach it to signal_idle()?

Comment: To call it just once, you can do this: Glib::signal_idle().connect_once(&loop);

Use sigc::mem_fun() if it's a member method.

To call it repeatedly you'd use connect() and you'd need a handler function that returns bool.

What exactly you do depends on how much work your function will do each time, and whether it needs to keep the main UI informed about what is happening.